# Django CreateView - How do I call form class __init__?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a django create view and I want to call the `__init__` of the form class and I don't know how to do that.

```
class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = PersonForm
```

In the form class I made some logic to redefine the queryset of some combos. My problem is that I don't know how to call the `__init__` method, or any other method, of the `PersonForm`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't call it yourself. You can override [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) to provide extra arguments to pass to the form instantiation.

```
class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = PersonForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super(PersonCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        form_kwargs['my_extra_queryset_param'] = get_my_extra_queryset()
        return form_kwargs
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The **init** method is actually called automatically by the class when a new instance of the object is instantiated.

Consider the following example:

```
class House():
    __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = x*y
```

To call **init**, we just do the following:

```
h = House(5,7)
```

This will create the object and automatically invoke the **init** function. It works the same way for django views.

I see Daniel beat me to an answer, perhaps his is more what you're looking for. Anyways, hope this helps a little at least!