# How does Django CreateView class instanciate models?

Tags: python, django

I have a basic model / form / views:

models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class TagCreate(CreateView):
    model = Tag
    form_class = TagForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view_somethin')
```

When using django-rest-frawework or Tag.objects.create(name="aagagaga"), the "name" field is passed to the `__init__()` of `Tag`, and i can do all hacks i want.

But when using the class based view, `__init__()` is of course called but no args are passed to. However, in the save method, i can check that the name attribute is already set to the good value.

My question is, how and where the data are transfered to the model instance if in case of class based views nothing is passed to the `__init__()` ??
I try to dig in the source code with no success, i suspect some king of manager

If you want to reproduce the issue, here is the testing code:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tag {self.name}"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.__dict__)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.__dict__)  # the filled attributes are here, but when were they filled ?
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)



Tag.objects.create(name="aagagaga")  # this call the __init__() with args as 
# intended but when using the html view, nothing is passed
```

Comment: check serializer `create` method.

Comment: Wich serializer ? the issue is not with drf, instead it works as intended with drf, but no with class based view, then i don't wich serializer your refer

Comment: sorry, disregard the comment, for some reason I thought this was drf related. Have you checked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077600/django-createview-how-do-i-call-form-class-init

Comment: No, but they speak about the instantiation of the view / form and not the model. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

So i found a way, i don't exactly how it works internaly but i suppose Django modify the attributes of the model on the fly.
Actually, the `form` stores a reference of the model instance in `self.instance`

So if you want to add/modify attributes like you would do in the `__init__()` of the model, you can do it by overriding `form_valid` of the `CreateView`:

```
class TagCreate(CreateView):
    model = Tag
    form_class = TagForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view_somethin')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.new_attribute = "new_thing"
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Then it appear in the model.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.__dict__)  # new_attribute appeared
        self.name += self.new_attribute
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Of course the new attribute is not meant to be saved in the database, but can be a useful modifier, like the current user.